# Capturing image from webcam

Tags: linux, camera, multimedia

I want to capture a image through webcam in Linux.
So I searched on the Internet and found out it's can be done using mplayer or vlc.

Following is the command for capturing image by mplayer and its corresponding error.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://

MPlayer SVN-r31628-4.4.4 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing tv://.
TV file format detected.
Selected driver: v4l2
 name: Video 4 Linux 2 input
 author: Martin Olschewski <olschewski@zpr.uni-koeln.de>
 comment: first try, more to come ;-)
v4l2: unable to open '/dev/video0': No such file or directory
v4l2: ioctl set mute failed: Bad file descriptor
v4l2: 0 frames successfully processed, 0 frames dropped.


Exiting... (End of file)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Please help me in solving this error.
I searched on the net and found out about v4l2, but still can't solve the problem.

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I am using Fedora in VMWare Workstation 9. I wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: On my laptops and desktop I can see my webcam with lsusb. Please paste the output.

Comment: @schaiba : I have edited the question. PLz check.

Comment: *sigh* Why wouldn't you think it important to say "Oh yeah, I'm running this through a virtual machine, and I haven't set it up to connect to the web cam yet" IN THE FIRST PLACE?

Comment: I'm sorry. That's all i can say now.
Do you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah. Configure your VM to connect the webcam.

Comment: now webcam is detecting. But there is another problem.
when i run above command, only green colour png picture appear.

Answer (score 2):

For capturing images from webcam, I would suggest [Cheese](https://projects.gnome.org/cheese/).

If Cheese doesn't solve your problem, it will at least help you debug it easily. Cheese does that: capture image from a webcam. You don't have other thousand functions to interfere with this task.

Comment: +1 mplayer is a bit low-level for the simple snapshot the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
fswebcam 000.jpg
```

then check out

`fswebcam --help`

It is useful enough that you can write a batch script and just have it run repeatedly to do some security camera things with it